# Is there an alternative for bindfs for android?

Tags: android

I want to bind directory with fake permissions on android. I tried bindfs on Ubuntu and it's working very well but there is not bindfs for android.

I'm using this to command to achieve this on Ubuntu:

bindfs -u 1000 -g 1000 -p 0755 /path/to/src /path/to/dest

Can I do it on Android?

Answer (score 1):

You have to build one yourself from  the source for Android using [bindfs](https://bindfs.org/) source or thank [this guy](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=4349826312261681311) who did it. Read [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217741/how-to-bind-mount-a-folder-inside-sdcard-with-correct-permissions)